# Bookmark & navigation on an iFrame that is coming from a different secured domain

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there any way to run a bookmarklet and have navigation on an iFrame which is from a different secured domain?

For example, I have a page loaded from https://example.com, which has an iFrame whose source is set to https://example2.com. When I run the bookmarklet, it is always run on example.com, since that is the main page. I want to run it on the other iFrame though and be able to navigate.

Otherwise is there any other solution rather than Iframe to implement as I'm asked to load an external secured web page with some links on it on my main website and get bookmarking and navigation working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the bookmarklet on the content of an iframe because the javascript runs on the main window. Which then gives security issues if you try accessing the iframe which you no doubt have run into.

One solution is to create a server side script that will fetch the content of the site you want and display it so that it appears to come from the parent domain. But that then opens another can of worms as you have to deal with all the relative pathing for things like pictures, and other files that were supposed to be hosted on an external site.

Oh and then there's the issue of whether the site owner wants you doing that in the first place and might set up barriers to prevent you from doing this, i.e. checking the referer header value and denying access.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback, the site that I wanna display is secured(https) and belongs to another branch of our company is there any way to create an exception for a specific domain to be able to get the content and how? as i tried using file_get_content() and cURl and failed not only because of the security but also links of the external site move me back to that last and the purpose is being able to navigate on this content on my site(exactly what iframe offers)